# Reading Files Asynchronously on Meteor

Tags: asynchronous, meteor

I am very new to Meteor so if my apologies if this is a dumb question:

How do you read a file from the filesystem on the server side, and get those contents displayed on the client side. Doing it synchonously isn't a problem because I can return it right away but as I understand from reading that defeats the purpose of Meteor so I am trying to do it asynchronously. However I dont know how to connect the client/server in this fashion. Publish/Subscribe seem to only be for db collections and not filesystem files. Any guidance you can give me would be very much appreciated.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
Template.body.helpers({
            myfile: function(){
                    return file_contents;
            }
    });
}


if (Meteor.isServer) {
     Meteor.methods({
     myfile: function(){
                    var fs = Npm.require("fs");
                    fs.readFile('/opt/SI/SIAgent/conf/myfile','utf-8', function (err, data) {
                    file_contents =  data;
                    });

             }   
     });
```

}

Comment: I think you want to look into Meteor Methods. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/methods_header

Comment: I am able to call the server method but dont know how to get teh data back asynchronously. Basically id like to update the page with the current contents of a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Meteor.wrapAsync` to turn Node.JS `fs.readFile` into synchronous-looking code so that you can return the result within the Meteor method.

```
var fs=Npm.require("fs");
fsReadFileSync=Meteor.wrapAsync(fs.readFile,fs);

Meteor.methods({
  getMyFileContent:function(){
    return fsReadFileSync("/opt/SI/SIAgent/conf/myfile","utf-8");
  }
});
```

Comment: or you can just use [fs.readFileSync](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) :)

Comment: The problem with `fs.readFileSync` is that it's truly synchronous and will block Node event loop contrary to fibers' synchronicity which is only making asynchronous calls look like synchronous code using syntactic sugar. `fs.readFileSync` is really something you only want to use in Node based CLI for example.

Comment: Great point! I guess I should have thought of that... we currently don't have any wrapped functions in our codebase so this isn't an issue that I've previously contemplated. Thanks for the reminder.